# React Native Bridge not returning correct value to javascript

Tags: swift, react-native

I'm trying to build a native module to use AVFoundation. I need to write a function in Swift that returns a value to javascript, so I have followed the instructions on [Exporting Swift](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#exporting-swift).

Here are my 3 resulting files:

**MediaManager.swift**

```
@objc(MediaManager)
class MediaManager: NSObject {

  @objc(getFrame)
  func getFrame() -> Int {
    return 123;
  }
}
```

**MediaManagerBridge.m**

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MediaManager, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getFrame)

+ (BOOL)requiresMainQueueSetup
{
  return NO;
}

@end
```

**Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

When I run `console.log(MediaManager.getFrame())`, I get "undefined".
When I run `console.log(MediaManager.getFrame)`, I get:

```
ƒ fn() {
        for (var _len2 = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len2), _key2 = 0; _key2 < _len2; _key2++) {
          args[_key2] = arguments[_key2];
        }

        var lastArg = args.length …
```

which is definitely not the function that I exported. I'm finding it a bit difficult to parse the docs - what have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is only for constants.

Use this

```
  func getFrame(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
callback([123])
```

}

and in react native do this

```
MediaManager.getFrame(
      (value) => console.log(value),
    )
```

Comment: And then instead of `@objc(getFrame)`, what would you use? Looking for documentation on this, but knowing next to nothing about Swift makes it a bit tricky to navigate.